# Mule Security (3.8)：how to use my basic-security-filter to deal the username and password from the form

Tags: spring-security, mule

1:there is my config

```
<flow name="SpringExample">
    <http:listener config-ref="alan-http" path="/mule-security" doc:name="HTTP"/>
      <logger level="INFO" message="## received" doc:name="Logger"/>
      <http:basic-security-filter realm="myFilter">
      </http:basic-security-filter>
      <mule-ss:authorization-filter requiredAuthorities="ROLE_123"/>
      <set-payload doc:description="" doc:name="Set Payload to a constant string" value="hello alan"/>

  </flow>
```

2:the filter receive the username and password as flow that is raw.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRbjp.png)

3:the quetion is : I want to make my filter to deal the username and password.
Please help,Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `<mule-ss:http-security-filter realm="mule-realm"/>` instead of `<http:basic-security-filter>` for Basic security filter.

Comment: thanks.but I find another way.
using <custom-security-filter class="com.eshore.dep.security.filter.AuthorizationFilter"/> instead of <http:basic-security-filter>